# Different delay tipe for the same process Arena

Tags: process, resources, delay

I need to change the delay type of a process during the simulation in Arena. For example I need a delay type `costant` for the first two hours and then a `triangular` delay for 3 hours.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting a decide just before the process. In that decide you can give conditions about the time decision. For instance, if the current time is at 2 hours, its exit point will go to an assign module that will assign its process time to a wanted constant. Or if it is 3 hours then it will go to another assign that will assign the process time of that current entity to a triangular distribution.

After that you can connect all these assigns to the "process" module and enter the delay type as an expression which will be the attribute you choose to assign the process times.